# Will an external battery power bank power an mini-ITX board (~200W)?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, power, voltage

I was planning to build a laptop from scratch, and I've found some good DC-DC converters that allow you to use an external power source to power a standard desktop board (in this case a mini-ITX). The build I have in mind will have a peak wattage of about 193W. I read on the specifications on Anker's website that the maximum output is (DC output: 12V / 4A, 16V / 3.5A or 19V / 3A), that comes out to be 57W max, right? Or does that only apply to charging another battery.
So my question is, will the power supply be able to pull more power than the max rating, or can I just not use this battery?

Am I missing something? Sorry I don't really understand how power supplies work. Any help would be appreciated, I don't want to destroy anything.

Thanks in advance,

M

Comment: It looks like you're right about 57W max (and there might also be current limitations or else the 12V output would be able to support 4.75A).  You lost me with "charging another battery".  You can't power a 193W board with 57W (and the board is not the only thing requiring power).  Also, what part of "max" rating isn't clear?  If you could pull more, that wouldn't be the max.  Can you expand your question to better describe exactly what you're looking at doing?

Comment: I apologize for sounding like an idiot. I found someone online who has already done what I'm trying to do and he has told me to use 8x 3.7V and 2500mah li ion cells into a protective circuit. The max output here is 30A, so I'm pretty safe in terms of power. Also I miscalculated my max power draw. It shouldn't be greater than 124W under 100% max load.

Answer (score 0):

193 Watt is quite a lot of power draw for a new mini ITX based system - indeed you should revisit your numbers as, while I guess this is possible - particularly if you have a heavy graphics card - but you will need to look at cooling issues as well.

You can't power a device which requires 193 watts with a battery which only allows 57 watt draw (well, I guess you could with the correct circuitry, some capacitors/super-caps and strict constraints on how long you can draw peak current for - but not practically).

Also, are you sure you are not confusing watts (ie instant power usage) with Watt Hours or Amp/Hours ?